# Solving a Differential Equation in a Limit where Terms Tend to Infinity

Tags: limits

I have the equation $\displaystyle \frac{d^2 \psi}{d \xi^2}
   +  \frac{1}{\xi}\frac{d\psi}{d \xi}
      + \left(\frac{n+s+1/2}{\xi}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{s^2}{\xi^2}\right){\psi(\xi)}=0 $

I was asked to solve the equation in the limits that:

1. $\xi $  goes to $\infty$
2. $\xi$ goes to $0$

The first part was simple because several terms dropped to $0$ and I was left with a simple differential equation with an exponential solution.  However, I am not sure how to deal with the second limit. It seems that $3$ of the terms go to positive or negative infinity, and at different rates.  I am not sure how to deal with these terms, or in general how to treat a divergent limit in a differential equation.  Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is what you give an ODE or a PDE? Your symbol "$\partial$" points to the latter while "$\psi(\xi)$" points to the former.

Comment: Sorry, it should be an ODE.  I'm new to Latex so I copy pasted an equation from somewhere else.

Comment: Do you have any constraints on $n$ and $s$?  Initial conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should be careful about believing that "solve the equation" and "take a limit of a parameter" is a pair of operations that commute.  This is treacherous if any of the terms of the differential equation vanish in the limit and *especially* treacherous if the equation is singular, meaning that the leading term is vanishing in the limit.

As given, we are to solve the equation, then take limits.

The general solution to your differential equation is
$$  \psi(\xi) = c_1 \mathrm{e}^{s \ln(\xi) - \xi/2}U(-n,2s+1,\xi) + c_2 \mathrm{e}^{s \ln(\xi) - \xi/2} L_n^{(2s)}(\xi)  \text{,}  $$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are constants of integration, $U$ is the confluent hypergeometric function of the second kind, a.k.a. Tricomi confluent hypergeometric function ([ref1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html), [ref2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Integral_representations)), and $L_n^{(a)}$ are the $n^\text{th}$ generalized Laguerre polynomial ([refa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials), [refb](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html)).

The $\lim_{\xi \rightarrow \infty} \psi(\xi)$ is a directed (complex) infinity depending on the details of $n$ and $s$ and on the $c_2$ of any particular solution.  Assuming $n$ and $s$ are real, we have 
$$  \lim_{\xi \rightarrow \infty} \psi(\xi) = \left(\frac{c_2 \Gamma(n+2s+1)}{\Gamma(-n)\Gamma(n+1)} \right) \infty $$

I'm not convinced the limit as $\xi \rightarrow 0$ even exists until we pick a particular solution.

Added in Edit:  What behaviour did you want at $\xi = 0$?

[image: n=s=-1]

[image: n=s=1/2]

Similarly, what behaviour did you want at $\xi = \infty$?  (Note these are $\psi(1/\xi)$ for $\xi \in (0,1]$.)

[image: n=s=-1]

[image: n=s=1/2]

As explained above, the limit as $\xi \rightarrow \infty$ depends on the signs of a few terms.  The previous two were showing what happens as $c_2$ changes sign -- i.e., the limit depends on which particular solution you choose.

Comment: I asked someone who is familiar with the problem and they said that I should multiply the equation by ξ so that the first, third, and fourth terms can be neglected (because they approach 0 or are dominated by the diverging terms) and the second term should be kept because the behavior of dψ/dξ isn't known.  That way the equation is reduced to two terms and is solvable via other methods.  I'm not sure if that is a mathematically "treacherous" approach, but that was how I was advised to solve it.  Thank you for your answer though, I appreciate it and understand your point!

Comment: @safaroth2 : Added a few plots which might clarify that the limits you ask about depend on which particular solution you choose.  So, to evaluate these limits, we need boundary or initial conditions (to pick particular solutions).